# Swiching between 2 diferent NSViewControllers with data

Tags: swift, macos, navigation

I'm absolute newbie in Swift and OSX development, and I'm sorry if my question will be too noob.  I want to understand principles of navigation between NSViewControllers.

I have my default `ViewController`, where are login and password fields and button to login. After click on button, returns token. And now I trying to change "view" to `SecondViewController` and save somewhere token, I will need it in future. How can I do it? and it possible to do this in function?:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
   .... 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Related (it's about iOS, but lots of things apply to macOS as well): https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/3151675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `segues` to perform this action.

First make the `segues` connections between the `ViewControllers` using to storyboard editor. After that you need to give the `segues` an identifier on the storyboard's attributes inspector. Then in your code you can call the new `ViewController` by the `segue` like the code below.

With this code you can pass the data using the button:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var dataToPass: String = "DataToPass"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "segueIdentifier"), sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "segueIdentifier" {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destinationController as! ViewController2

            destinationViewController.dataToReceive = dataToPass
        }
    }
}


class ViewController2: NSViewController {

    var dataToReceive: String

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

And with this code you will use the `override viewWillAppear`

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var dataToPass: String = "DataToPass"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "segueIdentifier"), sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "segueIdentifier" {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destinationController as! ViewController2

            destinationViewController.dataToReceive = dataToPass
        }
    }
}


class ViewController2: NSViewController {

    var dataToReceive: String

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

In both cases you need to assure the data you want to pass to the other view controller is not null.

Comment: Thank you for help. Now I can transfer data when I click button. But when I'm trying make seque between two `ViewControllers ` I have only (show/modal/sheet/popover/custom) options. Is some possibility to show ViewController2 in initial window? Replace ViewController to ViewController2.

Comment: You can change the inicial view controller on your storyboard, but this way you will not be able to pass the data to it as it will be the first view controller. Another way you can do is to perform the segue on `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` keeping the `override prepare` passing the data.

Comment: I didn't understand how to do it. Can I ask you for a code sample? Thank you one more time!

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the example. Take a look.

Comment: Will check it tomorrow morning, now I’m away from computer. But thanks anyway!

Comment: When I run programm open 2 windows... It doesn't replace ViewControllers.

Comment: But the `segue` in Swift for MacOS creates a new window. It's the normal behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164740/discussion-between-guidupas-and-danila-kulakov).